# Limits with continuous functions

Tags: limits, continuity

I'm really stuck on this question and I'm not really sure on where to begin.

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions defined on R.

Suppose that $f(2) = 2$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow2} f(x) − 6f(x)g(x) = −10$.

Determine the value $g(2)$.

Comment: please learn mathjax. Although I like the little arrow character you found. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any continous function $f$, $$ \lim_{x \to x_0} = f(x_0) $$

Adding and multiplying continuous functions preserves continuity, so the limit statement you mention
$$ \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) - 6f(x)g(x) = -10$$ is equivalent to
$$f(2) - 6f(2) g(2) = 2 -12 g(2) = -10 $$
from which once concludes $$ g(2) = 1$$

Answer (score 3):

It's a well known fact that if $h\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $p\in\mathbb R$, then
$$\lim_{x\to p} h(x) = h(p).$$
Using that fact, we conclude that
$$f(2) - 6f(2)g(2) = -10.$$